# Invalid request error in symfony on Linux server

Tags: php, linux, symfony

I have developed i web application in symfoy2, my development environment is Windows (using wamp server), but when deployed it on a Linux server, there is a page which gives me the "invalid request" error, i checked the URL and Parameters, also the query, everything were the same, it works in windows but not in Linux. is there any case sensitive problem? or variable naming and parameters?

Comment: Does your code in controllers throw `new HttpException(400...`?

Comment: Please post more details, such as full error message, HTTP code (404, 50*) and maybe the part of the code where the exception is being thrown. Also info about the server: is it a VPS or shared hosting?

Comment: yeas the code is inside the controller, and the full error is "invalid request" there is no any error number and something else. the server is shared, and also same error in our local Linux server.

Comment: You should check your error log file. There should be more datails about problem.

Comment: Give us content of your `error_log` file and try to `php cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: Have you also checked the case of the name of the controller and action? And the location of the controller class? Windows is case-insentive, but Linux isn't.

Comment: Are you using the development front end controller app_dev.php? The production controller app.php doesn't display error messages.

Comment: Thanks all, I solved it, after i checked the error_log i found the problem, the error was that such file is not exist, then controller name was started in Lower Case but the URL which i have specified were started in Upper Case,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Case Sensitivity, My controller was named like viewSalarayTEmplate.php but the link to this file were specified like: `<a href="directory/ViewSalaryTEmplate">click to view</a>` then i change my code to : `<a href="directory/viewSalaryTEmplate">click to view</a>` i found the problem after i checked the error log file and it was "the directory is not exist".